# How can I get jQuery chosen plugin to collapse a select box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

Perhaps this isn't a problem with the chosen plugin but that is where I'm encountering the problem.  The chosen plugin draws the select box just fine.  The problem is that select box if fully displayed and clicking an element in the select box doesn't collapse the selection. By fully displayed I mean, when the section is displayed, the selection appears as though it has been clicked and all of the options are visible and won't go away.

Anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

This template is loaded after the page load by using .on().

There is a  block at the bottom of the loaded template and it is calling the chosen() function on
the element.

```
<script>
    (function() {
        $('.chzn-select').chosen();
    )()
</script>
```

In the html the select box is defined as:

```
 <select id="product_id" class="chzn-select"  onchange="update_values()">
```

I don't really think this is related to the chosen plugin. I've tried quite a few of the different parameters from the docs and nothing is changing it.

Comment: If you open up your web console and call `$(".chzn-select").trigger("liszt:updated")` does that change anything?

Comment: No. It just printed Object[ ].

Answer (score 2):

dont use the inline onchange event. if you are using jquery already you should use it to add your on change event as well.

That being said I am wondering if there is a conflict on the change event because of the way the plugin sets it self up on the element. would need to see more code to be sure.

try doing something similar to this...

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen().change(function() {
    alert('change happened');
    //to close the chosen (not pretty but will work. note this will close all open chosens)
    $('.chzn-container-active').trigger('click')
});
```

Comment: Well, that fired.  I'm not sure how to collapse the dropdown though.

Comment: not pretty but gets the job done... $('.chzn-container-active').trigger('click')

Comment: That didn't do anything for me.  The only way I was able to get the list of options to go away is to hide() it.  Then I can't click the select box and set it to show().  I'm wondering if this has to do with chosen() being called after the page loads.  Clicking the selection does what it is supposed to do when I click one of the options.  It just won't go away unless I call hide().  The drop down covers other form elements so it's a problem.

Comment: I just threw a little test together and it works fine. There is most likely a problem somewhere in the html or JS on the page.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, where the options expanded down the page and wouldn't disappear after I selected one. After creating the simplest possible html page and still having the issue, I realized I hadn't linked to chosen.css which is included in the zip file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scripts/chosen/chosen.css">
```

As soon as I copied chosen.css and all of the other files from the zip file to my "scripts/chosen" folder and added the above link to chosen.css, chosen worked just like the demo.